# Remap array columns to single column with value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, array, union

Here is the sample database schema.

```
| id |  Critical     |  High  |    Low     |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  | {apple, ball} |  {cat} | {dog, egg} |
```

Now I want to remap these to another table. Critical set to 1, High to 2 and Low to 3 like:

```
| element | priority |
----------------------
|  apple  |   1      |
|  ball   |   1      |
|  cat    |   2      |
|  dog    |   3      |
|  egg    |   3      |
```

1,2,3 can be changed to column name too.

I've written a query to do it for 1 column at a time:

```
insert into new_table (element, priority)
select unnest(critical), 1 from old_table where id=1;
```

But I want to do all the 3 columns in this single query.

I want it fast performing. Is `UNION` the most efficient way?

Comment: *is UNION the most efficient way?* UNION ALL seems to be the only way. Especially when some particular value may be a part of array in any column. PS. Your JSON is strange. `{}` means this is an object but the value looks like an array which must be enclosed with `[]`.

Comment: Sorry. Its actually array. I represented the way postgresql does

Comment: Still, `UNION ALL` is the way to go.

Comment: Like I commented on another question of yours, why are you using arrays to store the data rather than a true normalized relational model?

Answer (score 0):

**`UNION ALL`**, not `UNION`:

```
SELECT id, unnest(critical) AS element, 1 AS prio FROM tbl
UNION ALL SELECT id, unnest(high)     , 2         FROM tbl
UNION ALL SELECT id, unnest(low)      , 3         FROM tbl;
```

Optionally drop the `id` (like in your displayed result), but I suspect you need it.

For big tables, a **`LATERAL` subquery may be faster** as it only uses a single sequential scan:

```
SELECT sub.*
FROM   tbl t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT id, unnest(t.critical) AS element, 1 AS prio
   UNION ALL SELECT id, unnest(t.high)        , 2
   UNION ALL SELECT id, unnest(t.low)         , 3
   ) sub;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8b4444dd9ba28ffe7d4f6872ddc32569)*

Otherwise, this question seems like a subset of your later more complex question:

- [Unnest ids from arrays based on priority with no duplication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/287027/unnest-ids-from-arrays-based-on-priority-with-no-duplication)