# Unnest ids from arrays based on priority with no duplication

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, array

Here is the sample schema for my database:

```
Priority  | Productive | UnProductive | Neutral |
-------------------------------------------------
  High    |   [1, 2]   |      []      |  [4, 5] |
  Medium  |   [3, 4]   |    [5, 7]    |   [2]   |
  Low     |     [1]    |    [2, 6]    |    []   |
```

NOTE: These numbers are actually UUIDs in my database and no numbers will be repeated in the same row.

I want to unnest the category from `productive`, `unproductive` and `neutral` such that:

- Not any from 1 to 7 numbers are repeated and
- If the number is already captured by **High** Priority it will not be captured by **Medium** and same goes for **Low**.

Expected output:

```
Productive: [1, 2, 3]  # no 4 because it have been captured by neutral High priority
UnProductive: [7, 6]  # no 5 and 2 because it have been captured before
Neutral: [4, 5]  # no 2 because it is caputed before
```

Comment: Unnest all. Add total relative weight (summarize per separate value, High=6, Medium=3, Low=0, Productive=2, UnProductive=1, Neutral=0). Select highest weight per value. Compact, calculate category.

Comment: could you please elaborate or add it as answer @Akina

Comment: Replace (or add) table-formatted sample data with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Add expected output formatted as an output table.

Comment: Currently I am trying to do similar like you've just said implementing a temporary table in a function. The issue was that the temporary table was not recognized during the later insert commands. @Akina

Comment: You can use dbfiddle.uk to show us how you input the data into tables - this will also give us the table DDL - please also add the same information to the question. This looks to be quite a complex and interesting SQL/programming problem - it may require a RECURSIVE CTE **unless** you are **certain** that you will only ever have High, Medium and Low priorities and Productive, Unproductive and Neutral states.

Comment: Why are you using arrays to store the values rather than a true normalized relational design? Why not have columns `priority` (with values High, Medium, Low), `category` (with values Productive, UnProductive, Neutral) and a third column with the ID? It becomes *much* easier to process!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be cast as [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem in disguise. So `DISTINCT ON` is my core feature after unnesting and before aggregating back:

To produce one row like in the original table:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, CASE priority WHEN 'High' THEN 1 WHEN 'Medium' THEN 2 WHEN 'Low' THEN 3 END AS prio
   FROM   tbl
   )
SELECT array_agg(id ORDER BY prio) FILTER (WHERE state = 'p') AS productive  -- ORDER BY prio?
     , array_agg(id ORDER BY prio) FILTER (WHERE state = 'u') AS unproductive
     , array_agg(id ORDER BY prio) FILTER (WHERE state = 'n') AS neutral
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
   FROM (
                SELECT unnest(neutral) AS id, prio, 'n' AS state FROM cte
      UNION ALL SELECT unnest(productive)   , prio, 'p'          FROM cte
      UNION ALL SELECT unnest(unproductive) , prio, 'u'          FROM cte
      ) sub1
   ORDER  BY id, prio, state
   ) sub2;
```

Or with pivoted result:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, CASE priority WHEN 'High' THEN 1 WHEN 'Medium' THEN 2 WHEN 'Low' THEN 3 END AS prio
   FROM   tbl
   )
SELECT state, array_agg(id ORDER BY prio)  -- ORDER BY prio?
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
   FROM (
                SELECT unnest(neutral) AS id, prio, 'neutral' AS state FROM cte
      UNION ALL SELECT unnest(productive)   , prio, 'productive'       FROM cte
      UNION ALL SELECT unnest(unproductive) , prio, 'unproductive'     FROM cte
      ) sub1
   ORDER  BY id, prio, state
   ) sub2
GROUP  BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c9b5b8a6786a02afed49a896a9ccf13b)*

Further reading:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

You did not mention performance in this question. Consider the answer to your previous question for this:

- [Remap array columns to single column with value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/287022/remap-array-columns-to-single-column-with-value/287085#287085)

Comment: Brilliant!! <3 Thank you

Comment: If i have `All = {1,2,..10}` and I want to have a new row/column: `Rest = {8,9,10}`. (remaning unseen numbers). How can I add them here?

Comment: @Pax: Sorry, I don't understand. Maybe start a new question with all relevant details?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this relationaly by unnesting and assigning the weights as suggested by @Akina.

```
with weighted as (
  select
    case priority
      when 'High' then 6
      when 'Medium' then 3
      when 'Low' then 0
    end as priority,
    productive,
    unproductive,
    neutral
  from
    data
), unnested as (
  select
    unnest(productive) as id, priority, 2 as category 
  from
    weighted
  union all
  select
    unnest(unproductive) as id, priority, 1 as category 
  from
    weighted
  union all
  select
    unnest(neutral) as id, priority, 0 as category
  from
    weighted
) 
select
  case category
    when 0 then 'Neutral'
    when 1 then 'UnProductive'
    when 2 then 'Productive'
  end,
  array_agg(id)
from unnested x
where not exists (
  select null
  from unnested
  where id = x.id
  and priority + category > x.priority + x.category
)
group by category, 1
order by category desc;
```

See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8a54e1f8018c49146faba3e446f7b694

It can probably be done more efficiently.